# A comical/informal synonym for "big"/"large" but not inappropriate

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english

I'm looking for a comical word that has a meaning like big, humongous, etc. but nothing inappropriate that would contain swear words.

For example, I could say:

```
Whoa! That's a ______ spider!
```

Slangs are acceptable, but not necessary. I'm looking for a word that might make a reader giggle at the type of adjective used to describe it.

Comment: **ginormous** or **humongous** come to mind.

Comment: You might say *whopping*. It sounds a bit quaint/old-fashioned to my ears, and might have a funny(ish) effect because of that. Definitely family-friendly.

Comment: @onomatomaniak you should post it as a suggestion. *That's a whopper* does sound amusing. I like it!

Comment: Fans of _The Lord of the Rings_ would understand the reference if you called it _Shelobistic_. In California surfer/stoner talk, the term might be _mondo_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### A gigantical spider

*Gigantical* is made up, it should be *gigantic*. However, if you are aiming towards a humorous tone, (you did say you wanted your reader to giggle) try playing around with words.

- A spundacular spider (inspired by *spun*, the past tense of *spin*)
- The enormousness of a spider (*enormity*)
- A mammothal spider (*mammoth*)
- A grandioso spider (*grandiose* = impressive)
- A super-mega spider (mega = big)

Comment: Excellent suggestions, except for _enormousness,_ which I think most speakers would interpret as a noun and ungrammatical in this context. I would suggest something like _enormorundo_ instead to fit with the spirit of the other suggestions.

Comment: @BraddSzonye I was about to say "I like your enormorundo", when I realized it might sound rude. I'll make an edit to emphasize that ungrammatical mistake which I think adds to the humour. Saying "enormousness" sounds funny, and a bit of a tongue twister, which kids especially love.

Answer (score 5):

I can think of a few:

- *brobdingnagian*
- *ginormous*
- *gargantuan*

Answer (score 1):

I have heard people come up with the terms "elephantocious", "huge-mongous", "big-a-licious", "bignormous" and the cracker was "krakendous"

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use something contextual. Lets say, you actually wanted to use this adjective o descibe a spider. Imagining one with a giant torso,

> Thats one giant haystack of a spider!

Sorry, I'm not really that witty. But i hope you got the idea :)